# How do you logout of Neo4j Web admin console

Tags: neo4j

Using Neo4J v2.2.3 community version.

From inside web admin console does anyone know of any way to log out?

Comment: I am in v 2.1.x and I don't need any authentication to log in the web admin, did they change that in 2.2.x ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

type this in tnto the browser's input line:

```
:server disconnect
```